# RequireJS in symfony

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, requirejs

i'm a new developer on symfony2 framework and i'm getting some difficulties in fact : i'm trying to integrate a full front open source application which is developed with AngularJS (angularjs-Quizzler). 
But when i'm integrating the project i didn't know where to put some files. for example : i got a JavaScript file which use other JavaScript files:

```
    head.js(

  { require    : "./vendor/requirejs/require.js",                  size: "80196"   },
  { underscore : "./vendor/underscore/underscore.js",              size: "43568"   },

  { angular    : "./vendor/angular/angular.js",                    size: "551057"  },
  { ngRoute    : "./vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js",        size: "30052"   },
  { ngSanitize : "./vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",  size: "19990"   }

)
```

so i'm getting this in my browser console :

```
http://localhost/RSS/web/vendor/underscore/underscore.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost/RSS/web/vendor/requirejs/require.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost/RSS/web/vendor/angular/angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost/RSS/web/vendor/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost/RSS/web/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

i've tried hearsay RequireJs Bundle but it seems complicated to use, there is probably a softer solution. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer but i didn't work like that to get a solution, after a stressing day i've found a way to resolve my problem by simply modifying the URLs in my "main.js" to make it understandable by symfony
example:

```
{ require    : "./vendor/requirejs/require.js",                  size: "80196"   }
```

becomes

```
{ require    : "/MyProjectName/web/bundles/mybundle/js/vendor/requirejs/require.js",                  size: "80196"   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put them in web directory in a js directory.

And call them in twig like that each time {{asset('js/script.js')}}

Exemple :

```
{ require    : "{{asset('js/require.js')}}", size: "80196"   },
```